# Get the script command of a child process?

Tags: process

Is there a way to retrieve the script command responsible for a child execution?
For example:
If I run in a script called `runX arg1 arg2` (X being the process name)

```
[some code]
X arg3 arg4
```

now when I check the commands of each of the child and parent

```
PID=`pidof X` # PID of X
PPID=`cat /proc/$PID/status | grep PPid ` # PPID of X
CMDP=`cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline` # this will return the shell name rather than runX arg1 arg2
CMDC=`cat /proc/$PID/cmdline` # this will return X arg3 arg4
```

I'd like to retrieve this command instead `runX arg1 arg2`